# How to create %hash which will be contains key => name of file, value => file contents?

Tags: perl

For exemple, I have 1 file **8854**

File contest is:

```
ABCSDESG
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work with your code? And where is it?

Comment: i have no way...

Answer (score 0):

```
my $file = '8854';
my %hash = ( $file => `cat $file` );
```

Comment: You are not building a hash but a reference to hash. Why a system call? **Never** use system call in a script when you can use core functions.

Comment: @Toto You are right about the reference (fixed). Its the habit of using references. As for the "never use a system call" -> never say never. I did use it because the notation is more terse, because I did not want to write code to read a file and because I did not want to use libraries. If you look at the question...he just wants a lead, so I believe that a very simple code could give him one